# Oracle SQL What does start_date-1 mean?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL What does start_date-1 mean?

Is it just one day less the start_date?

Comment: What is the datatype of start_date ?

Comment: Yes, 1 day earlier than start_date.  You can also add and subtract fractions of a day e.g. start_date+1/24 is an hour later than start_date.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your datatype is a date or timestamp, yes, it will remove a full day from your date:

```
SELECT SYSDATE AS "start_date", 
  SYSDATE - 1 AS "start_date -1" 
FROM DUAL;
```

Returns

```
26/08/2015 11:09:21 | 25/08/2015 11:09:21
```

Answer (score 0):

YES. It will subrtract 1 day from the start_date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is 1 day earlier to start_date.

Comment: Since when `DATEADD` is introduced in **Oracle**?

Comment: It does not, there is an add_months function, but there is no need for a dateadd since one can directly add the number of days to the date.

Comment: I did not notice it is for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the data type of `start_date` is **DATE** or **TIMESTAMP**, subtracting `N` from it would subtract `N` number of days.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT sysdate, sysdate -1 FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE             SYSDATE-1
------------------- -------------------
26-08-2015 14:45:35 25-08-2015 14:45:35

SQL>
```

Remember, date has both **date and time elements**, so you will go back to previous day with exactly that time portion.